# Extract contents out of a website's HTML source using regex

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I have the following code that I'm trying to get fixed.

The code:

```
$pageData = file_get_contents('111234-2.html');
if(preg_match_all('/<a\s+onclick=["\']([^"\']+)["\']/i', $pageData, $links, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
     print_r(array_unique($links[1]));
return false;
```

Some sample HTML where I want it to fetch from:

```
    <a onclick="doShowCHys=1;ShowWindowN(0,'http://www.example.com/home/Player.aspx?lpk4=116031&amp;playChapter=False',960,540,111234);return false;" href="javascript:void(0);">
<span class="vt">Welcome

        </span>
        <span class="dur">1m 10s</span>
        <span class="" id="bkmimgview-116031">&nbsp;</span>
        <br class="clear">
    </a>
```

The output I am getting:

```
Array ( [0] => doShowCHys=1;ShowWindowN(0, )
```

The output I am hoping for:

```
Array ( [0] => doShowCHys=1;ShowWindowN(0,'http://www.example.com/home/Player.aspx?lpk4=116031&amp;playChapter=False',960,540,111234);return false;)
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is it that you want to match?

Comment: Also, you're probably going to see some people make comments about how you shouldn't use regex to pasrse html, and the reason for that is because regular expressions don't handle hierarchical structures like HTML.  certain html structures can mess your gegex up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can improve this using a backreference but you're pretty much doomed if there's any more levels of nested quotes.

```
'/<a\s+onclick=(["\'])((?:(?!\1).)+)\1/i'
```

The backreference lets you refer to an already-captured group. So, if you caught a `"` in the first capture, then you want to find a string of non-`"`s, and likewise, if you caught a `'` in the first capture, then you want to find a string of non-`'`s, and either way end up with that same quote, `"` or `'` respectively.

**EDIT:**

@vladr offers a much nicer alternative:

```
'/<a\s+onclick=(["\'])(.*?)\1/i'
```

Same idea but the non-greedy quantifier makes it unnecessary to test every character for non-whatever-quote-ness. Updated Rubular link: http://rubular.com/r/VXR1nQ4zf5.

Comment: Here's a Rubular demo: http://rubular.com/r/TAXwfPv0yd.

Comment: or `/<a\s+onclick=(["\'])(.*?)\1/i`.  Either way, the OP's code should change to refer to `$links[2]` now.

Comment: @vladr - Oh, very nice. Not sure why I didn't think of that. Good points.

Comment: FWIW, http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php lets you play with PHP regexps interactively.